# Drupal Commerce and Commerce Multicurrency

Tags: commerce

How do I change the currency of the checkout using a rule?

Currently I have the shop changing the price of a line item based on region/language and with this changing the currency. It works well in switching the price of the line items and the overall total, using a couple of rules.